# Parallax scrolling tutorial for background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, skrollr

After spending days trying to figure out why I can't seem to get parallax scrolling working for one picture on a website I'm working on, I'm finally posting here. So I have this code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
[a bunch of stuff here]
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro {
   background: url(../images/IMG_100.png) 50% 0 fixed; 
   background-position: center;
   margin: 0 auto; 
   width: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   padding: 100px 0;
}
```

I've pretty much tried all the tutorials for a simple parallax scroll effect, but they don't seem to work for my situation as it stands. What seemed most promising to me was to use the [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) plugin - I tried adding the following to my div tag:

```
<div id="intro" class="intro"
        data-bottom="opacity:1;background-position: 0px -50px;"
        data-center="opacity:1;background-position: 0px 0px;"
        data-top="opacity:1;background-position: 0px 50px;">
```

I then initialized skrollr at the end of my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        skrollr.init();            
    }
</script>
```

...doesn't work. I'm fairly new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know you're missing a closing `</div>` at the end of `id=intro`? Can you provide a demonstration of what "doesn't work"? Try http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: perhaps I'm doing something wrong with the javascript? here's a fiddle of something that works in fiddle, but not when I it locally http://jsfiddle.net/XFj82/3/ @DThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `id` of your main div should be equal to `skrollr-body` and not `intro`.

1st EDIT

Actually, I see there are situations where the main `id` doesn't need to be named `scrollr-body`. Maybe [this tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/) could help you achieve different effects since I couldn't find any official documentation.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prYG5/) of your snippet from the question.

2nd EDIT

I changed your html code to this

```
<section id="skrollr-body">
    <div class="intro"
        data-bottom="opacity:1;background-position: 0px -50px;"
        data-center="opacity:1;background-position: 0px 0px;"
        data-top="opacity:1;background-position: 0px 50px;">
        <h1>Content in here</h1>
        <p>first big text block</p>
        <p>second huge text block</p>
    </div> 
</section>
```

I also changed the `background` attribute of the `.info` class to this

```
background: url('bg-image.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
```

but feel free to experiment with values. Check the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFj82/6/)

Comment: I tried that tutorial, it didn't seem to work for me :(. I think it might be something with my javascript that I'm using, perhaps I'm not using skrollr.js properly?

Comment: @eggrollers Post your code on [link](jsbin.com) or [link](jsfiddle.net) and I'll try to solve the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pfwv5/ this is pretty much what I have so far, I removed a bit of what I had inside the main intro div tags as it didn't seem too relevant. I have another js file linked, but as far as I know that one is only responsible for smooth scrolling up and down the page (I left the links in there in case they're of any importance). @hex494D49

Comment: @eggrollers Check the updated answer. And play with the `background attribute` according to your background image.